# VIM copy a full word that contains a . (dot)

Tags: vim, vi

i noticed that that if a word contains . (dot), then ywi will only copy until the dot. yet I want to the entire word copied

whole.word  should copy whole.word, and not just whole

Comment: Are you looking to change default vim behavior, or are you looking for the shortest way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried in gVim and looks like either yE or yW will work for you.

---

Oh, sorry. you want to copy. Maybe using yWi would work?

---

Did you try dW ? I think that should ignore the punctuation.

Comment: This is the first time I've ever seen top-posting on SO.

Comment: Really? I just figured I'd put my latest comments on top.

Comment: it confuses me :( Normally it goes like .. comment 1\n; edit: comment2\n; update: comment3

Answer (score 8):

yE

(putting nothing here to reach the character limit)

Answer (score 4):

You can either use `yE` or `yiW`. I prefer the latter, even though the it involves an additional keystroke, because it will produce the same result no matter where your cursor is positioned on the `whole.word` string. In vim's terminology, the `w/b/e/ge` commands each operate on a 'word', whereas the uppercased commands (`W/B/E/gE`) operate on a 'WORD'. You can read up on the differences by running [`:help word`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#word) in Vim.

Answer (score 4):

If there's a *space* after the word you'd like to copy, you could type `yt<space>` which would ***y***ank un***t***il **space**. If there's no space after the word, then yank until the separating character.